# All in one PC won't connect to WiFi after Windows 10 update

Tags: windows-10, wifi-configuration

I can't enable one protocol to get it to connect to the WiFi. It let me enable all the others except one called `Microsoft network adapter multiplexor protocol`.

I check the box to enable it, and every time it says:

> Your current selection will disable the following features: Microsoft
>   network adapter multiplexor protocol.  Are you sure you want to
>   disable these feature(s)?

Um... no, I just want to be able to get online on my new computer.

Comment: Your question is hard to read. Can you make some effort and format it, use paragraphs as this single block of content is probably going to be ignored. You can [edit your question](http://superuser.com/posts/1073738/edit)

Comment: Restore your operating system from a best restore point.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question with the make and model of your PC?

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that the machine won`t be available to connect to the Internet after upgrade to Windows 10, right?

First of all, please ensure your device manufacturer website has released the Windows 10 compatible drivers for your model machine.

For the network issue, we could refer to the following link to have a troubleshoot.
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-sg/windows-10/fix-network-connection-issues

In addition, please try to run the built-in troubleshoot tool to have a diagnostic.
Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Troubleshooting\All Categories\Network Adapter